# Adding zeros spaces to an array of a picture

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have an image defined as:

```
imagen = scipy.misc.imread("C:\\Users\\Reymi\\Downloads\\imagen.png")
```

It has a size of (1929,1280)
I need to add 2 columns and rows with zeros to each side of the array so I can use a kernel without worrying about it going outside of the array.

How? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use the `pad` function:

```
im_new = scipy.pad(array=imagen, pad_width=[2, 2], mode='constant', constant_values=0)
```

The above function makes the array bigger by 2 in all directions.  If you wanted to *replace* the outer two pixels with 0's without making the picture larger I don't *think* there is a built-in function, but I would do something like:

```
pad = 2
im_new = scipy.zeros_like(imagen)
im_new[pad:-pad, pad:-pad] = imagen[pad:-pad, pad:-pad]
```

This creates an image of 0's, then fills in the middle with the middle part of `imagen`.

Comment: Or, if using numpy, `np.pad(imagen, ((0, 0, (2, 2), 'constant')`

Comment: it is asking for a "mode" argument. Also what is sp? scipy?

Answer (score 0):

Option - 1 - Using OpenCV

```
imagenBorder = cv2.copyMakeBorder(imagen,2,2,2,2,cv2.BORDER_REFLECT)
```

Option - 2 - Manually padding to numpy array

```
import numpy as np    
borderWidth = 2
i = 0
while i < borderWidth:
    imagen = np.insert(imagen, 0, 0, axis=1)
    imagen = np.insert(imagen, imagen.shape[1], 0, axis=1)
    imagen = np.insert(imagen, 0, 0, axis=0)
    imagen = np.insert(imagen, imagen.shape[0], 0, axis=0)
    i = i+1
```